# Why do some polygons appear completely one shade when rendered?

Tags: lighting

When I modeled a shoe (the polygons might be bad as I usually don't model) and rendered it, some of the polygons appeared to be all one shade even though the shoe was all shaded smooth (same problem when some parts were not shading smooth). The material on this is the default, lighting is one sunlight, and rendering settings are default.

[image: Model of the shoe]
[image: LookDev mode with lights on]
[image: Rendered]

Comment: It must be the famous Terminator effect, i.e. pixellation on the border of shadow, it should be fixed in the next Blender version, but you should be able to fix it if you increase the light size

Comment: I'm using a sunlight light so I don't think I can increase the size. I am on alpha 2.81 though, and thanks for the response.

Comment: in 2.8 it's called Angle